# Using Google Sheets, how can I calculate the average per month based on multiple rows?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet where I am entering Groceries on each row every time I visit a store. I have calculated the overall sum, but now I would like to calculate the average cost per month for the groceries.

[image]

I don't even know where to begin on this. I have posted my spreadsheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R0zYMAigDULzm8oM2icsPK55BP162kVvctpx2cOSOIE/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in B5. It will take the year and month into account (so 1/7/2018 will count as a separate month from 1/7/2017). It counts unique year-month combinations and divides the sum spent. The minus one accounts for the blank cell counted as unique.

```
=sum(B9:B)/arrayformula(countunique(text(A9:A,"YYYY-MM"))-1)
```

Comment: That works great Ed! Thank you! I'm trying to wrap my head around the code you wrote. When I try to use `=arrayformula(countunique(text(A9:A,"YYYY-MM")))` it returns `4` when there are `3` unique months. I noticed you subtracted by `1` in order to make up for that, but do you know why the number is off by one?

Comment: Since I used A9:A a blank cell will be included in the count. If you define it as A9:: the last row with data, this wouldn't happen, but you would have to adjust the formula (unless you inserted the row manually). If this works for you, please approve the answer by clicking the check mark by the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

same answer, using double query:

`=QUERY(
QUERY({A8:B},
"select year(Col1), month(Col1), sum(Col2) group by year(Col1), month(Col1)"),
"select avg(Col3) label avg(Col3) ''")`

The inside query is report with sums by years and months:

formula:

`=QUERY({A8:B},
"select year(Col1), month(Col1), sum(Col2) group by year(Col1), month(Col1)")`

result:

```
year(Date)  month(Date) sum Amount

2016            10          133.00
2017            0            80.00
2017            1           420.00
```

Months are zero-based: 0 - Jan, 2 - Feb...

Comment: Thanks for your answer Max. Unfortunately that doesn't take into account multiple years :(